# How to change Fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am learning Android and stuck at this.
I want to make a project in Android. In MainActivity I have a button and want to set onClick() event such that pressing it, if button's text is "SOLVE" then add fragment Output and change button's name to "BACK" and if button's text is "BACK" then add fragment Input and change Button's text to "SOLVE".

Here's my MainActivity.java code

```
package com.example.sudokusolver;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Button a        
String check ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        a=(Button) findViewById(R.id.press);
        check=a.getText().toString();


        a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
             public void onClick(View v){

                if(check.equals("SOLVE")){

                     Output OP=new Output();

                     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                     FragmentTransaction ft =
                     fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                     ft.add(R.id.frag,OP);

                     ft.commit();

                     a.setText("BACK");
                }
                else
                {
                    Input IP=new Input();

                     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                     FragmentTransaction ft =
                     fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                     ft.add(R.id.frag,IP);

                     ft.commit();

                     a.setText("SOLVE");

                }

             }
        });

    }

}
```

here's main_activit.xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/frag"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        />

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/press"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/show" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is (you might have seen) I can't compare ( *check* string) non-final variable inside an inner class. SO please help me with this and if you think my whole idea is wrong then suggest me proper way.

(if other files require then tell me, I will edit)

**EDIT**

There is something wrong with my logic. when I first press 'Solve' it turned to 'Back'. But when I press 'Back' it doesn't turn to 'Solve'. I want Solve > Back > Solve > Back... am i missing something? (maybe in add/replace transaction ?)

Comment: define views globally..no need to handle final..

Comment: If the button has no use other than this no need to declare it `final` or declare it globally. Just use the `view` from the arguments in the `onClick`. The `view` there is the `Button` itself

Comment: There is something wrong with my logic. when I first press 'Solve' it turned to 'Back'. But when I press 'Back' it doesn't turn to 'Solve'. I want Solve > Back > Solve > Back... am i missing something? (maybe in add/replace transaction ?)

Comment: declare the button at class level it will solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

Replace `if(check.equals("SOLVE"))` with `if(((Button)v).getText().toString().equals("SOLVE"))`.

To set a new text use this 
`((Button)v).setText("YourText")`

In `OnClick` the view is getting passed as the argument is the `Button` itself. So you can manipulate the view as `Button` and set or get its properties

Comment: Ya it works! but there is still problem with a.setText("BACK")

Comment: this answer has been flagged as a low quality answer, please provide some explanation

Comment: dont use `a` inside the `onClick` listener. Use the `view` that is passed as arguments

Answer (score 1):

To be able to access variable `a` (your Button) inside of anonymous classes created in some method, you need to declare the variable final. Example:

```
final Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.press);
```

Make `check` (your String) final too, as it's used in the anonymous class also:

```
final String check = a.getText().toString();
```

Comment: @DhavalGondaliya OP said nothing about using this variable globally. Furthermore his given code doesn't imply that either. I don't see how that's *good* :) Just adds an unnecessary line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Define your button as class variable as

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Button a;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    a =(Button) findViewById(R.id.press);
```

and compare in listener as

```
if(a.getText().toString().equals("SOLVE")){
```